# GraphicsMagick / ImageMagick replace all non-transparent pixels (like Photoshop's Color Overlay)

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, gm

I'm trying to replace all non-transparent pixels to a given color using [GraphicsMagick for Node](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm).

Using a composite image is not an option, I simply need to change every non-transparent pixel to a given color.

**Original image:**

[image: Original image]

**Goal:**

[image]

Transparent pixels should stay transparent. I'm trying to achieve Photoshop's Color Overlay effect:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit simpler. In ImageMagick do the following:

```
convert 84xHk.png -fill "#E91FCB" +opaque none result.png
```

[image]

Comment: works perfect with ImageMagick - but would like to execute this using GraphicsMagick, however the same commands (`gm convert 84xHk.png -fill "#E91FCB" +opaque none result.png`) gives this output: `gm convert: Unable to open file (none) [No such file or directory].`

Comment: Sorry, I do not know GraphicsMagick. It was an early spin off of Imagemagick and may not have all the same features or they use different names for those features. My guess is that it does not understand +opaque. You may have to use one of emcconville's methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Node's GraphicsMagick library, but there are a few methods to achieve this. Here's a few I can think of...

**Extract alpha, and replace colors**

```
convert 84xHk.png -alpha extract \
        -negate -fill '#E91FCB' -fuzz 50% \
        -opaque black output.png
```

[image: First Example]

**Create solid color image, and copy alpha channel**

```
convert 84xHk.png \
       \( +clone -alpha off \
          -fill '#E91FCB' \
          -draw 'color 0,0 reset' \
       \) +swap -compose CopyOpacity -composite output.png
```

[image: Second Example]

**Use FX expressions**

```
 convert 84xHk.png -fx 'p.a==1?#E91FCBFF:#E91FCB00' output.png
```

[image: Third Example]